# How to find this integral using Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

How to obtain that $$\int\limits_{|z|=r} (\bar{z})^{-m} z^{-n-1}\, dz = \begin{cases} 2\pi ir^{-2m} &\text{if}\,\,n=m, \\ 0 &\text{if}\,\,n \neq m, \end{cases}$$ for $r>0$.

I suppose I have to use Cauchy integral formula:

- if $n=m$ then we have $$\int\limits_{|z|=r} (\bar{z})^{-m} z^{-m-1}\, dz=\int\limits_{|z|=r} (\bar{z})^{-m} z^{-m}\, \frac{dz}{z}=\int\limits_{|z|=r} |z|^{-2m} \frac{dz}{z-0}=2\pi i |0|^{-2m}=\begin{cases} 2\pi i, m=0\\ 0,\quad m \neq 0\end{cases}$$ and I am confused.

I could use $z=re^{i\theta}$ to obtain $$\int\limits_{|z|=r} |z|^{-2m} \frac{dz}{z}=\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}r^{-2m}\, i \, d\theta=2\pi i r^{-2m},$$ but what is wrong with my first way?

- for $n \neq m$ I would do same, and then result would be $2\pi i \bar{0}^{-m}0^{-n}=0$ using Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: In your first way, $|z|^{-2m}=r^{-2m}$ so is a constant to be pulled out, and the remaining integral is that of $1/z$ around the circle, which is the $2\pi i$, so the two answers agree.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, that is right, but what is wrong to define $f(z)=|z|^{-2m}$ and then use Cauchy integral formula? In other word, I don't want to pull $|z|^{-2m}$ out

Comment: Even if you leave the constant $c$ in, the Cauchy integral formula will have $c/z$ to integrate, giving $2\pi i \cdot c.$

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, yes, but look at mrf solution. That was problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your first "approach" is incorrect is that the function
$$f(z) = |z|^{-2m}$$
is *not* holomorphic (except when $m=0$). Cauchy's integral formula is only valid for holomorphic functions.

Comment: Ahhh, yes. Function $f(z)=|z|$. Where is my brain... Thank you!

Comment: And I forget to ask: is my solution for $n \neq m$ correct?

Comment: @user110822 Hard to say, but probably not. It looks like you are applying Cauchy's integral formula to $f(z) = \bar z^{-m}z^{-n}$ which again is *not* holomorphic.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So I will use $z=re^{it}$ for that part, that is safe.

Answer (score 1):

In your first way, you should have done like that

$\int\limits_{|z|=r}|z|^{-2m}\frac{dz}{z} = r^{-2m}\int\limits_{|z|=r}\frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi ir^{-2m}$, because |z| is constant on the curve |z|=r.

(as **coffeemath** said)

Comment: Thank you for response. Look at @mrf solution. That was problem for me.